# The Art of R Programming : Where else could I find the information?

Tags: r

I came across the editorial review of the book The Art of R Programming, and found this

> The Art of R Programming takes you on a guided tour of software development with R, from basic types and data structures to advanced topics like closures, recursion, and anonymous functions

I immediately became fascinated by the idea of anonymous functions, something I had come across in Python in the form of lambda functions but could not make the connection in the R language.

I searched in the R manual and found this

> Generally functions are assigned to symbols but they don't need to be. The value returned by the call to function is a function. If this is not given a name it is referred to as an anonymous function. Anonymous functions are most frequently used as arguments other functions such as the apply family or outer.

These things for a not-very-long-time programmer like me are "quirky" in a very interesting sort of way.
Where can I find more of these for R (without having to buy a book) ?

Thank you for sharing your suggestions

Comment: See here: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/First-class-functions

Comment: Read the source code---the R functions in the core R distributions are  very well written (albeit in an advanced fashion).  But you can also study the code of your favourite packages.

Comment: Thank you @hadley. I feel like I newbie all over again.

Comment: Some core r functions are well written.  Some are travesties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Functions don't have names in R.  Whether you happen to put a function into a variable or not is not a property of the function itself so there does *not* exist two sorts of functions: anonymous and named.  The best we can do is to agree to call a function which has never been assigned to a variable anonymous.

A function `f` can be regarded as a triple consisting of its formal arguments, its body and its environment accessible individually via `formals(f)`, `body(f)` and `environment(f)`.  The name is not any part of that triple.  See the [function objects](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Function-objects) part of the language definition [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html).

Note that if we want a function to call itself then we can use `Recall` to avoid knowing whether or not the function was assigned to a variable.  The alternative is that the function body must know that the function has been assigned to a particular variable and what the name of that variable is.  That is, if the function is assigned to variable `f`, say, then the body can refer to `f` in order to call itself.  `Recall` is limited to self-calling functions.  If we have two functions which mutually call each other then a counterpart to `Recall` does not exist -- each function must name the other which means that each function must have been assigned to a variable and each function body must know the variable name that the other function was assigned to.

Comment: I looked at the help for Recall, and its mind bending, but really interesting. How does one find these sort of things in R ???

Comment: Read the R manuals and the help files.  `library(help = base)` will list all the help files for the base package of R.  `search()` will list it and the other core packages and you can do the same with them.

Comment: To elaborate on @G.Grothendieck's comprehensive answer, one practical implication of `Recall()` being limited to self-calling functions means that you can't use it as an argument to an `*apply` function (see `?Recall`), which precludes its use in some typical recursive scenarios, like transversing a tree. For such cases, `rapply()` might be worth considering.

Answer (score 5):

There's not a lot to say about anonymous functions in R. Unlike Python, where lambda functions require special syntax, in R an anonymous function is simply a function without a name.

For example:

```
function(x,y) { x+y }
```

whereas a normal, named, function would be

```
add <- function(x,y) { x+y }
```

Functions are first-class objects, so you can pass them (regardless of whether they're anonymous) as arguments to other functions. Examples of functions that take other functions as arguments include `apply`, `lapply` and `sapply`.

Answer (score 4):

Get Patrick Burns' "The R Inferno"  at  [his site](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

There are several good web sites with basic introductions to R usage.

I also like [Zoonekynd's manual](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/all.html)

Answer (score 2):

Great answers about style so far.  Here's an answer about a typical use of anonymous functions in R:

```
# Make some data up
my.list <- list()
for( i in seq(100) ) {
   my.list[[i]] <- lm( runif(10) ~ runif(10) )
}

# Do something with the data
sapply( my.list, function(x) x$qr$rank )
```

We *could* have named the function, but for simple data extractions and so forth it's really handy not to have to.