# Print the Nth Row in a List of Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I am cleaning several excel files in R. They unfortunately are of unequal dimensions, rows and columns. Currently I am storing each excel sheet as a data frame in a list. I know how to print the 4th row of the first data frame in a list by issuing this command:

```
df.list1[[1]][4,]
```

Or a range of rows like this:

```
df.list1[[1]][1:10,]
```

My question is: How do I print a particular row for every data frame in the list? In other words:

```
df.list1[[i]][4,]
```

`df.list1` has 30 data frames in it, but my other `df.lists` have over 140 data frames that I am looking to extract their rows. I'd like to be able to store particular locations across several data frames into a new list. I'm thinking the solution might involve `lapply`.

Furthermore, is there a way to extract rows in every data frame in a list based on a condition?  For example, for all 30 data frames in the list df.list1, extract the row if the value is equal to "Apartment" or some other string of characters.

Appreciate your help, please let me know if I can help clarify my problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could also just directly `lapply` the extraction function @Justin suggests, e.g.:

```
# example data of a list containing 10 data frames:
test <- replicate(10,data.frame(a=1:10),simplify=FALSE)

# extract the fourth row of each one - setting drop=FALSE means you get a
# data frame returned even if only one vector/column needs to be returned.
lapply(test,"[",4,,drop=FALSE)
```

The format is:

```
lapply(listname,"[",rows.to.return,cols.to.return,drop=FALSE)

# the example returns the fourth row only from each data frame
#[[1]]
#  a
#4 4
# 
#[[2]]
#  a
#4 4
# etc...
```

To generalise this when you are completing an extraction based on a condition, you would have to change it up a little to something like the below example extracting all rows where `a` in each `data.frame` is `>4`. In this case, using an [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754961/496803) is probably the clearest method, e.g.:

```
lapply(test, function(x) with(x,x[a>4,,drop=FALSE]) )

#[[1]]
#    a
#5   5
#6   6
#7   7
#8   8
#9   9
#10 10
# etc...
```

Comment: Very helpful! I have been utilizing this method for a couple days now, but could you show me an example of extracting a row based on a condition? this is wrong, but you might still get the idea: lapply(test,"[",if(row="Apartment"),,drop=FALSE)

Comment: @geoQuant - I have edited my answer to include this - hope it helps.

Comment: `lapply(test, subset, a > 4)` as an alternative

Answer (score 5):

There is no need for a wrapper function, just use `lapply` and ***pass it a blank argument*** at the end (to represent the columns)

```
lapply(df.list, `[`, 4, )
```

This also works with any type of row argument that you would normally use in `myDF[ . , ]`  eg: `lapply(df.list,`[`, c(2, 4:6), )`

.

---

I would suggest that if you are going to use a wrapper function, have it work more like `[` does:   eg

`Grab(df.list, 2:3, 1:5)` would select the second & third row and first through 5th  column of every data.frame and 
`Grab (df.list, 2:3)` would select  the second & third row of all columns

```
Grab <- function(ll, rows, cols) {
    if (missing(cols))
        lapply(ll, `[`, rows, )
    else 
        lapply(ll, `[`, rows, cols)
}

Grab (df.list, 2:3)
```

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to write a function that does what you want on a single data frame:

```
myfun <- function(dat) {
  return(dat[4, , drop=FALSE])
}
```

If you want to return as a vector instead of `data.frame`, just do: `return(dat[4, ])` insteaad. Then use `lapply` to apply that function to each element of your list:

```
lapply(df.list1, myfun)
```

With that technique, you can easily come up with ways to extend `myfun` to more complex functions...

Comment: Cool approach. Thank you, but I can't seem to get myFun to run.

Comment: @geoQuant, it was a small oversight. It should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a .csv file called hw1_data.csv and you want to retrieve the 47th row. Here is how to do that:

```
x<-read.csv("hw1_data.csv")

x[47,]
```

If it is a text file you can use `read.table`.