# Simplify extraction of list of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

My question is a continuation of the following question. (Couldn't comment on that thread due to reputational constraints)

[Print the Nth Row in a List of Data Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038863/print-the-nth-row-in-a-list-of-data-frames)

I want the results to be printed as a data frame and not as a list (assuming I have multiple columns and not a single column as in the example). Can somebody tell me what I need to do to get this output?

Input sample list

```
    $AK
                    HospitalName State HeartAttack HeartFailure Pneumonia
    99  PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER    AK        13.4         12.4      10.5
    103         ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK        14.5         13.4      12.5
    102      FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AK        15.5         15.6      13.4
    106     ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER    AK        15.7         11.6      15.5
    100   MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AK        17.7         11.4      12.1

    $AL
                                  HospitalName State HeartAttack HeartFailure Pneumonia
    78                        CRESTWOOD MEDICAL CENTER    AL        13.3         13.8      10.4
    85                     BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER EAST    AL        14.2          9.6      10.2
    1                 SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL        14.3         11.4      10.9
    31                              GEORGIANA HOSPITAL    AL        14.5         10.8      11.3
    65                     PRATTVILLE BAPTIST HOSPITAL    AL        14.6         14.8      14.2
    60                                 THOMAS HOSPITAL    AL        14.7         12.8      13.1
    71           VAUGHAN REG MED CENTER PARKWAY CAMPUS    AL        14.7         12.0      14.0
```

Expected Output Sample ( assume num = 4, ie, extract 4th row of every dataframe)

```
    HospitalName State HeartAttack HeartFailure Pneumonia
    106     ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER    AK        15.7         11.6      15.5
    65                     PRATTVILLE BAPTIST HOSPITAL    AL        14.6         14.8      14.2
```

The lapply code I have used is printtab<-lapply(finaltab,'[',num,,drop=FALSE)

finaltab is a list of dataframes where each dataframe contains 5 columns, num is used to extract 1 particular row from each dataframe, printtab is the output list

Things I have tried:

1. Adding simplify=TRUE in lapply: It gives an error
2. Using sapply as printtab<-sapply(finaltab,'[',num,,drop=FALSE): It
   says argument is missing, with no default. Tried without drop as
   well.
3. Using as.data.frame(): Its doing something I don't understand

   > ```
   > AK.HospitalName AK.State AK.HeartAttack AK.HeartFailure AK.Pneumonia                AL.HospitalName AL.State
   > NA            <NA>     <NA>           <NA>            <NA>         <NA> D W MCMILLAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL       AL
   >    AL.HeartAttack AL.HeartFailure AL.Pneumonia                   AR.HospitalName AR.State AR.HeartAttack AR.HeartFailure
   > NA           15.7            14.8         12.6 ARKANSAS METHODIST MEDICAL CENTER       AR           17.1            14.4
   >    AR.Pneumonia                     AZ.HospitalName AZ.State AZ.HeartAttack AZ.HeartFailure AZ.Pneumonia
   > NA         11.7 JOHN C LINCOLN DEER VALLEY HOSPITAL       AZ           14.9            11.9         10.0
   >          CA.HospitalName CA.State CA.HeartAttack CA.HeartFailure CA.Pneumonia          CO.HospitalName CO.State
   > NA SHERMAN OAKS HOSPITAL       CA           13.3             9.7          9.3 SKY RIDGE MEDICAL CENTER       CO
   >    CO.HeartAttack CO.HeartFailure CO.Pneumonia         CT.HospitalName CT.State CT.HeartAttack CT.HeartFailure CT.Pneumonia
   > NA           15.0             9.9         10.5 MIDSTATE MEDICAL CENTER       CT           15.6            12.1         11.4
   >    DC.HospitalName DC.State DC.HeartAttack DC.HeartFailure DC.Pneumonia DE.HospitalName DE.State DE.HeartAttack
   > NA            <NA>     <NA>           <NA>            <NA>         <NA>            <NA>     <NA>           <NA>
   >    DE.HeartFailure DE.Pneumonia                FL.HospitalName FL.State FL.HeartAttack FL.HeartFailure FL.Pneumonia
   > ```

EDIT:

Sample Output for dput(head(finaltab))

```
    structure(list(AK = structure(list(HospitalName = c("PROVIDENCE ALASKA  MEDICAL CENTER", 
"ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL", "FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER", 
"MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER"), State = c("AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK"), HeartAttack = c("13.4", "14.5", "15.5", "15.7", 
"17.7"), HeartFailure = c("12.4", "13.4", "15.6", "11.6", "11.4"
), Pneumonia = c("10.5", "12.5", "13.4", "15.5", "12.1")), .Names = c("HospitalName", 
"State", "HeartAttack", "HeartFailure", "Pneumonia"), row.names = c(99L, 
103L, 102L, 106L, 100L), class = "data.frame"), AL = structure(list(
    HospitalName = c("CRESTWOOD MEDICAL CENTER", "BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER EAST", 
    "SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER", "GEORGIANA HOSPITAL",
```

Output for rbind on lapply

```
AK     AL     AR     AZ     CA     CO     CT     DC     DE     FL     GA     GU     HI     IA     ID     IL     IN    
[1,] List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5
     KS     KY     LA     MA     MD     ME     MI     MN     MO     MS     MT     NC     ND     NE     NH     NJ     NM    
[1,] List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5
     NV     NY     OH     OK     OR     PA     PR     RI     SC     SD     TN     TX     UT     VA     VI     VT     WA    
[1,] List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5 List,5
     WI     WV     WY    
[1,] List,5 List,5 List,5
```

Comment: It would help if you provided reproducible input and desired output... and included a question (with "?")

Comment: Could you edit into your question the output of `dput(head(finaltab))`?

Comment: @Frank- Added the reproducible input and the sample desired output.

Comment: @DavidRobinson- Thank you for editing! Took me a while to figure out ctrl+K does it quickly. And added the sample dput output. Should I add the entire output? It's pretty long

Comment: could you paste the output of dput completely?

Comment: this might work `data.you.need <-rbind(lapply(df.list, function(x) x[4,]))`. With your complete data or even the complete output of dput(head(finaltab)) we could test it

Comment: @infominer- I am unable to upload complete dput output because it exceeds character limit. The rbind is also not giving the output as expected. Adding to the question for your reference

Comment: can you upload the output of dput to dropbox or the whole dataset if you can share it?

Comment: @infominer- This contains the dataset and the entire code that I have done till now. The code is not well commented though https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hm4gre9m0o2n13t/AADX0eBrXebW2qrfMxD8TnlIa?dl=0

Comment: Downvote for posting console output of "rbind on lapply" without including actual code.

Comment: @BondedDust- Sure! Sorry, It was updated in response to infominer's comment but I understand that without reading the comments, it seems out of place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.meeshu has the output of dput. Your code didn't have anything about converting the csv file you had to the dput output. SO I just used the dput.
use your own dataframe which is finaltab in place of df.meeshu

```
df.list.select <-lapply(df.meeshu, function(x) x[4,])
df.select <-do.call("rbind", df.list.select)
head(df.select)
```

you can also use plyr,which might be quicker

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(df.list.select)
```

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate question and answer.

Comment: @infominer- Thanks, I tried the plyr and it works :) Found a few more methods as well!

Comment: @BondedDust, yup! decided to just answer it! Should've searched before taking the effort.

Comment: @BondedDust- Hey, you are right, it is. I didn't know that the correct search phrase would be "combining list of data frames". Got it in the past half an hour. I can delete this if that would be the best

Comment: @infominer- Done! New here so a little lost :)